# How to xUnit Test an ASP.NET 5 with Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, xunit.net

Using **Microsoft.Data.Sqlite**, it will try to locate the database file within the **wwwroot** directory by default of the ASP.NET 5 project(the Empty Template).

How to properly xUnit Test this kind of project? If I reference this ASP.NET project to my xUnit Test Project, it will surely use  the directory of the xUnit Test Project as the base.

**Update 1**

I want to perform an integration testing using xUnit. Thanks for someone who clarified things to me.

Comment: Do you want to write unit or integration tests? Or maybe even system test?

Comment: As of now, I just want to do a unit testing.

Comment: Then the answer is simple: Design your classes this way, that you can pass a mocked interface to the class you want to test. Database or file access in Unit Tests is an absolute no-go. A Unit Test should only test a unit of code of a specific class, **not** it's dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind unit tests is to only test a certain functionality of a class without it's dependencies (like database, file system or network).

In order to achieve this you need to design your classes with Inversion of Control in mind and abstract necessary types into interfaces.

Imagine a `OrdersService` class that may get the number of orders or total sum of all orders and you want to test it's logic.

```
public interface IOrdersRepository 
{
    IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersForCustomer(Guid customerId);
}

public class OrdersService : IOrdersService 
{
    private readonly IOrdersRepository ordersRepository;

    // pass the orders repository that abstracts the database access
    // as a dependency, so your OrdersService can be tested in isolation
    public OrdersService(IOrdersRepository ordersRepository)
    {
        this.ordersRepository = ordersRepository
    }

    public int GetOrdersCount(Customer customer) 
    {
        return ordersRepository.GetOrdersForCustomer(customer.Id).Count();
    }

    public decimal GetAllOrdersTotalSum(Customer customer)
    {
        return ordersRepository.GetOrdersForCustomer(customer.Id).Sum(order => order.TotalSum);
    }
}
```

Then in your unit test you'd do something like

```
[Fact]
public void CalculateOrderTotalSumTest() 
{
    // customer id we want to check 
    Guid customerId = new Guid("64f52c5c-44b4-4adc-9760-5a03d6f98354");

    // Our test data
    List<Order> orders = new List<Order>()
    {
        new Order() { Customer = new Guid("64f52c5c-44b4-4adc-9760-5a03d6f98354"), TotalSum = 100.0m),
        new Order() { Customer = new Guid("64f52c5c-44b4-4adc-9760-5a03d6f98354"), TotalSum = 50.0m)
    }

    // Create a mock of the IOrdersRepository
    var ordersRepositoryMock = new Mock<IOrdersRepository>();
    // Next you need to set up the mock to return a certain value
    ordersRepositoryMock
        .Setup( m => m.ordersRepositoryMock(It.Is<Guid>( cId => cId == customerId) )
        .Returns(orders);

    decimal totalSum = ordersRepositoryMock.Object.GetAllOrdersTotalSum(customerId);
    Assert.AreEqual(150.0m, totalSum, "Total sum doesn't match expected result of 150.0m");
    ordersRepositoryMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

This way you can test your classes in isolation without the need of a database. If you need a database, a file on the filesystem or network connection in a unit test, then you have done bad job on designing your types.

Comment: So unit testing is only for testing logics and not the full functionality of certain methods? So I'm not supposed to use the word or technical term "Unit Testing" in checking if I did broke something while developing my application? If this is the case, am I not also supposed to use Unit Testing tools? Then what kind of automated testing am I supposed to use to make sure that every functions are working properly?

Comment: Yes, testing logic or behavior (is method xyz of interface abc called during the test, can be done with mocks too). If you want to test multiple components interacting with each other, its called integration test. a system test tests the whole thing

Comment: I just looked at it and xUnit is capable of integration testing.

Comment: Basically every UnitTest framework is capable of integration tests. It's a matter of definition. UnitTests are more fine grained and you can test a specific functionality. If you only have integration tests, then changing of data breaks many tests which depend on it and a change in a module may break stuff on multiple places. Both tests are important for overall quality, they just test different things. You just don't want your unit test to break, because some other test or action changed a value in your database

Comment: But with the new changes with the new .NET Core, where AppDomain was removed, is there a way to run the main application in a contained environment that imitates the desired setup? One of the things I thought about is through calling the web methods but not everything is exposed in here.